# HttpClient not working on real device

Tags: android, android-emulator, http-get, htcsense

I use this code to do a HttpGet request to my web server. It works fine on emulator but not in my HTC Sense. The excecution just end without doing any http request. Any idea ?

```
File f = new File(user.getPhotopath());
List<NameValuePair> reqparams = new LinkedList<NameValuePair>();
reqparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", user.getEmail()));
reqparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pwd", user.getPassword()));
reqparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", user.getScreenName()));
reqparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photo", f.getName()));
reqparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("preference", user.getPrefs()));
reqparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bluetoothid", bid));

String urlstring = "http://www.mysite.com/me?"+ URLEncodedUtils.format(reqparams, "utf-8");

try {
    URL url = new URL(urlstring);

URI myURI = null;
try {
    myURI = url.toURI();
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
}
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(myURI);
HttpResponse webServerResponse = null;
HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
try {
    webServerResponse = httpClient.execute(getMethod);
    httpEntity = webServerResponse.getEntity();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (httpEntity != null) {

    InputStream instream = httpEntity.getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(instream));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            resultStr = sb.toString();
            instream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Indeed a stacktrace would be helpful, plus whether your emulator operates behind a proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your approach is correct and will work, it's much easier to use the [EntityUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html) helper class to retrieve the response body as a string. Simply:

```
String body = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know it existed xD.

Comment: Me neither - I discovered it after writing a similar method to you!

Answer (score 0):

There was no exception nor warning in stacktrace. Only memory allocation messages. Anyway i solved it by using URLConnection instead of HttpClient :

```
try {
      URL url = new URL(urlstring);
      URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
      InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
      BufferedInputStream bufferedInput = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

    // Read the response into a byte array
      ByteArrayBuffer byteArray = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
      int current = 0;
      while((current = bufferedInput.read()) != -1){
            byteArray.append((byte)current);
      }

      // Construct a String object from the byte array containing the response
     resultStr = new String(byteArray.toByteArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For some reason it worked. Still trying to figure what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks you all for your answers.